# Integration of exponential function.

Tags: integration, operator-theory

It is part of my research work in operator theory. I came across such a integration which became nightmare for me. I tried as all the possible ways. If anyone could help I would really appreciate.

Integrate $$\int_0^{2\pi} e^{-a\cos (\theta-b)} \; \;  \; \; \;d \theta $$ where a and b are real constants.

I would like to thank in advance for any help.

Comment: I don't think a closed form exists, but the integral can be written as an infinite series.

Comment: what is reason behind you think it does not exist? do you you mean by expanding exponential?

Comment: Have you tried differentiating under the integral sign ?

Comment: what you mean? we can easily differentiate exponential function, right?

Comment: you can try to use the so-called "expansion of plane wave" : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_wave_expansion where you adjust the parameters to look like your integrand...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that since the cosine function is $2\pi$-periodic, the integral is independent of $b$.  Therefore, we can set $b=\pi$ to find

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi }e^{-a\cos(\theta -b)}\,d\theta&=\int_0^{2\pi }e^{-a\cos(\theta-\pi )}\,d\theta\\\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi }e^{a\cos(\theta )}\,d\theta\\\\
&=2\int_0^{\pi}e^{a\cos(\theta)}\,d\theta\\\\
&=2\pi I_0(a)
\end{align}$$

where $I_0(x)$ is the [Modified Bessel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I.CE.B1_.2C_K.CE.B1) of the first kind and order $0$.

Comment: wow very good technique, thank you. But how do we know $ int_0^{\pi} e^{\a cos \theta } d\theta $ gives $I_0(a)$. I really wanna see a proof. Do you have some link of it?

Comment: See the link embedded in the answer.  That is the integral representation for $I_0(x)$.  ;-)) -Mark

Comment: There are many things to come up to Modified Bessel. I can trust you, but I am sorry it is not clear to me  why integration is $I_0$.

Comment: Look at the integral representations in the section that was linked.